# How make connections with subclassed UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

My project has a UIView located in a View Controller. The UIView has a subclass named AdminView. I want to add IBOutlets and IBActions on the subclass and connect them to controls on the UIView. I have found this is difficult to do with Xcode 8.2.1.

Image with IB and subclass set to AdminView
[image: IB with subclass set to AdminView]

At first I selected the UIView in IB. I then clicked the Assistant Editor hoping it would bring up my subclass. I first set the jump bar for the Assistant Editor to Automatic Mode. It didn't bring up the correct subclass in Automatic Mode. So next I put the jump bar for the Assistant in Manual mode and tried to navigate to AdminView.swift. Sometimes I couldn't do that because the Manual jump bar only showed interfaces.

Image with IB and Assistant Editor, side by side
[image: IB with Assistant Editor side by side]

Why doesn't Automatic mode select the proper file?
When in manual mode, why does it sometimes show interfaces rather than my .swift files?

When it works properly, I was able to navigate to my AdminView.swift file. Then I tried to control-drag connections from the IB to the file. Xcode would not make those connections.

Why was it not able to make connections?

Next I selected the UIView in IB and opened the Connections Inspector. The connections inspector showed the controls that are inside the view. I then tried to drag from the dots to the right of each control to AdminView.swift. That did not work either.

Image with IB and Connections Inspector
[image: IB with Connections Inspector]

Why did this not work?

Now for some good news. Next I went to AdminView.swift and added IBOutlets and IBActions for the objects in my UIView. I made sure to copy IBOutlets and IBActions from other parts of my project in order to make sure the syntax was correct. The I built the app. Dots appeared in the gutter next to the IBOutlets and IBActions I had just created.   Then I put AdminView.swift in the Assistant Editor. Now I dragged (not control-dragged) from those dots to their respective controls in IB. Thankfully, this made the connections I needed.

Image with some Outlets and Actions manually added
[image: IB with some Outlets and Actions added]

Image with some connections 
[image: IB with some connections]

Why was this the only method that worked?

Does anyone know of any other methods besides this to make these connections?

Is there anything I can do differently to make the other two methods of making connections work?

Comment: Could you include some images? That would help us to visualize what you're saying.

Comment: This was fixed by Apple in Xcode 8.3.1!!